# how to get first and last letter of every word in an arraylist in java

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

```
public static void ReadKeyWordsFile() {

        
        try {

            ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
            File file1 = new File("./files/kywrdsOdd.txt");
            if(file1.length() == 0){
                System.out.println("The files is empty");
            }
            else{
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(file1);
                while (scan.hasNextLine()){
                    result.add(scan.nextLine());  
                    
                }
            System.out.println(result);
            
            for (int counter = 0; counter < result.size(); counter++) {               
                int l = result.size() -1; 
                System.out.println(l);
            }
            scan.close();
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            //TODO: handle exception
            System.out.println("File not found");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

But this returns only the size of the array and not the words in it.
I want to get occurence of the first and last letter from each words in the array

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## tl;dr

```java
int[] codePoints = "Mask".codePoints().toArray();
if ( codePoints.length > 0 )
{
    String firstLetter = Character.toString( codePoints[ 0 ] ) ;
    String lastLetter = Character.toString( codePoints[ codePoints.length - 1 ] ) ;
}
```

> k

## Avoid `char`

When working with individual characters, learn to use Unicode code points. The `char` type in Java is [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), and should be avoided. The `char` type cannot represent even half of the characters defined in [Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode).

## Code points

The [Unicode Consortium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_Consortium) has assigned an integer number to each of the 143,859 characters recognized so far (Unicode 13.0, 2020-03). These numbers range from zero to just over a million. These numbers are known as [code points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point).

You can get a stream of the code point numbers assigned to each of the characters in your string. Calling [`String#codePoints`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#codePoints()) returns an [`IntStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/IntStream.html). We can [convert that to an array of `int` values](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#toArray()).

From our array we can pull the code point integer for the first and last characters of each input string. We convert those code point integer numbers back to textual characters by calling [`Character.toString`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Character.html#toString(int)).

```java
List < String > list = List.of( "Alice" , "Bob" , "Carol" );
for ( String s : list )
{
    IntStream codePointsStream = s.codePoints();
    int[] codePoints = codePointsStream.toArray();
    if ( codePoints.length > 0 )
    {
        int firstCodePoint = codePoints[ 0 ];
        int lastCodePoint = codePoints[ codePoints.length - 1 ];
        System.out.println( Character.toString( firstCodePoint ) + "/" + Character.toString( lastCodePoint ) );
    }
}
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/jtvN8y).

```
/e
B/b
C/l
```

We could shorten this code, though not necessarily an improvement.

```java
List < String > list = List.of( "Alice" , "Bob" , "Carol" );
for ( String s : list )
{
    int[] codePoints = s.codePoints().toArray();
    if ( codePoints.length > 0 )
    {
        System.out.println( Character.toString( codePoints[ 0 ] ) + "/" + Character.toString( codePoints[ codePoints.length - 1 ] ) );
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't believe I wasn't aware that char was legacy, although it's kind of obvious when you think about it, and it must have been for ages - never seen it explicitly mentioned anywhere and never spotted to think about it.

Comment: @daniu Yes, `char` has been essentially broken for many years. The type was defined as 16-bits, enough for the 64K worth of characters that the original Unicode team naïvely thought would be enough to handle most languages including [CJK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CJK_characters). Soon after Java 1.0, it became apparent Unicode would need many more characters for additional obscure Chinese characters, the various academic interests, and later emoji. Java 5 brought formal support for the full range of later Unicode versions. But `char` type is hobbled. Code point methods were bolted on.

Comment: @daniu For more info, see: [*Unicode Versions Supported in Java-History*](http://www.herongyang.com/Unicode/Java-Unicode-Version-Supported-in-Java-History.html) and [Supplementary Characters in the Java Platform](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/javase/supplementary.html) by Norbert Lindenberg and Masayoshi Okutsu, Sun Microsystems, Inc., May 2004.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `charAt()` method in Java,

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add("maneesha");
    list.add("cloud");
    list.add("piercer");

    for (String s : list) {
        System.out.println((s.charAt(0)) + " " + (s.charAt(s.length() - 1)));
    }
}
```

and the output will be,

```
m a
c d
p r
```

here in `m a` first letter is `m` and last letter is `a`

Comment: This code breaks with most characters defined in Unicode. Try: `list.add( "maneesha" );`